# How to do index search in row template? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I hope you're having a nice day.

I'm a newbie with JavaScript, specially with WebComponents and HTML templates, I'm developing a simple table that pulls data from a public API Rest, this is the table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFOv1.png)

and this is HTML code that's structuring table with the template #row:

```
<body>
<div id=botones></div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <template id="row">
            <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Next, the code where I do the calling from the API Rest, it's worth mentioning that in the for loop I'm cloning template's content and introducing the data of the API array result and appending to tbody tag every row as the iteration marks.

```
function generateTable(){
const row = document.querySelector('#row');
const tbody = document.querySelector('table>tbody');

fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
    .then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200){
            return response.json();
        }else{
            alert("No hay datos");
        }
    })
    .then(data=>{
        for(var j=0 ; j<data["data"].length;j++){
            const clone = row.content.cloneNode(true);
            const tds = clone.querySelectorAll('td');
            tds[0].textContent = data["data"][j]["employee_name"];
            tds[1].textContent = data["data"][j]["employee_salary"];
            tbody.appendChild(clone);
        }
    })
}



function search(){
var input, filter,table, tr, td, i, txtValue,tbody,temp;

input = inputIndex.value.toUpperCase();
filter = input;
table = document.body.getElementsByTagName('template');
tr = table.content;
// tbody = table.getElementById('#cuerpo_tabla');
// temp = tbody.getElementById('#row');
// tr = temp.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
    td = tr[i].getElementsByClassName("celda")[0];
    if(td){
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if(txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter)>-1){
            tr[i].style.display ="";
        }else{
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem comes when I try to do an index search, introducing a key and clicking the button of search index, debugger throws that browser is recognizing template #row but is not recognizing its content, row and cells thus for loop can't do iteration and compare the content in rows and next, throwing the search, I tried to do this by DOM as you can see but it does not works.

If someone that knows about this can help me, I'll be grateful!!

Thanks a lot and best regards! :)